# Camel custom service to expose jmx methods - Exception: no security manager: RMI class loader disabled

Tags: security, apache-camel, rmi, jmx

i successfully added a custom class that implements org.apache.camel.Service to expose some functionality. All methods returning void work fine. Now i added a method that returns a String (multiple lines). Calling this with jconsole or MissionControl yields:

```
    java.rmi.UnmarshalException: Error unmarshaling return; nested exception is: 
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException (no security manager: RMI class loader disabled)
    at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.executeCall(StreamRemoteCall.java:246)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(UnicastRef.java:161)
    at com.sun.jmx.remote.internal.PRef.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl_Stub.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnector$RemoteMBeanServerConnection.invoke(RMIConnector.java:1029)
    at com.jrockit.mc.rjmx.internal.MCMBeanServerConnection.invoke(MCMBeanServerConnection.java:234)
    at com.jrockit.mc.rjmx.services.internal.MBeanOperationsWrapper$MBeanOperation$1.call(MBeanOperationsWrapper.java:133)
    at com.jrockit.mc.rjmx.ui.operations.ExecuteOperationForm.createInvocationResult(ExecuteOperationForm.java:143)
    at com.jrockit.mc.rjmx.ui.operations.ExecuteOperationForm.access$9(ExecuteOperationForm.java:138)
    at com.jrockit.mc.rjmx.ui.operations.ExecuteOperationForm$3.widgetSelected(ExecuteOperationForm.java:125)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:248)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1053)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4169)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3758)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runEventLoop(Workbench.java:2701)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2665)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2499)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$7.run(Workbench.java:679)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:668)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    at com.jrockit.mc.rcp.application.Application.start(Application.java:26)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1414)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException (no security manager: RMI class loader disabled)
    at sun.rmi.server.LoaderHandler.loadClass(LoaderHandler.java:393)
    at sun.rmi.server.LoaderHandler.loadClass(LoaderHandler.java:185)
    at java.rmi.server.RMIClassLoader$2.loadClass(RMIClassLoader.java:637)
    at java.rmi.server.RMIClassLoader.loadClass(RMIClassLoader.java:264)
    at sun.rmi.server.MarshalInputStream.resolveClass(MarshalInputStream.java:214)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1612)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1517)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1771)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1990)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1915)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1798)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:370)
    at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.executeCall(StreamRemoteCall.java:244)
    ... 35 more
```

Since i am using the apache camel layer for jmx i ask if there is some camel way to fix this?

Comment: Does your method throw an exception when its being called? Maybe try to ensure no exception is thrown and that a String value is returned. Maybe even try just to hardcode and return "Hello" etc.

Comment: Thanks Claus this was the problem, the logging was turned off for tests :-P. Now it works. If you write your comment as answer i will accept it - it might help others (the exception is somewhat missleading).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your new method throws an exception such as `javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException` which on the callee side (eg from jconsole etc) is not on the classpath.

Maybe try to ensure no exception is thrown and that a String value is returned. Maybe even try just to hardcode and return "Hello" etc. And if any exceptions is supposedly to be thrown then favor only using exceptions from the JDK itself so you wont have classpath issues like this.